# Importar archivo de Excel. QT. Interfaz Grafica

Tags: c++, qt, interfaz-gráfica, qt-creator

Buen día comunidad.

Necesito de su ayuda para poder leer importar información de un archivo de Excel a mi programa en QT Creator. El problema que tengo es el siguiente:
Al llegar a la linea: `vBT.push_back(new Abonado(cNom, cApe, cDia, cMes, cAni, cCod));` me marca error.

Abonado es una clase que hereda de la clase Persona, hereda: Nombre, Apellido, Fecha (Fecha es composición en Persona y tiene las variables Dia, Mes, Anio).

Al llegar a esa linea que les mencione arriba no logro hacer matching.

Me gustaria que revisen todo el metodo y me ayuden a modificarlo para que me funcione.

Los datos del archivo Excel se deben ver en un tableWidget.

Saludos.

```
vector<Persona*>Abonados::PersonasExcel(vector<Persona*>vBT,QString filename){

   //SecreaunobjetodetipoQFileyselepasacomoparametrounnombredearchivo
   QFile ExcelPersonas(filename);

   //Importantisimavalidaciondequeelarchivoexiste
   if(!ExcelPersonas.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text)){
       qDebug()<<"Elarchivonopuedeserleido";
       //return;
     }

   //CreaunObjetodeFlujodeTextodetipoQT,lollamamosxIN,yselepasacomoparametroelrchivoabierto
   QTextStream xIN(&ExcelPersonas);
   //DEESTAFORMALEEELARCHIVOLINEAALINEAYLODESCOMPONEENCAMPOS
   while(!xIN.atEnd()){
       //leecadalinea
       QString linea=xIN.readLine();
       //haceelsplitencampos,enunobjetotipoLISTAQT
       QStringList registro=linea.split(",");

       //DividimoslaListadePersonas
       QString campoNom=registro.at(0);
       QString campoApe=registro.at(1);

       QString campoDia=registro.at(2);
       QString campoMes=registro.at(3);
       QString campoAni=registro.at(4);

       QString campoCod=registro.at(5);
       QString campoCar=registro.at(6);

       //PasamosaStringStandardparaenviarelparametroalObjeto
       string cNom=campoNom.toStdString();
       string cApe=campoApe.toStdString();

       int cDia=campoDia.toInt();
       short cMes=campoMes.toShort();
       short cAni=campoAni.toShort();

       int cCod=campoCod.toInt();
       string cCar=campoCar.toStdString();

       vBT.push_back(new Abonado(cNom, cApe, cDia, cMes, cAni, cCod));
       //muestraloscampos
       //qDebug()<<registro;
     }
   //Secierraelarchivom
   ExcelPersonas.close();
   return vBT;

 }
```

Comment: "*Al llegar a la linea: `vBT.push_back(new Abonado(cNom, cApe, cDia, cMes, cAni, cCod));` me marca error*" ¿Qué error? ¿Error en tiempo de compilación o error en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: Añadí una respuesta amigo. 
Espero sepas ayudarme, en este caso la clase es Empleado.
Saludos.